# Android - Error with screen rotation and bitmap in android

Tags: java, android, bitmap, android-bitmap, bitmapimage

My app takes pictures of my website, images can be shared with whatsapp and other social networks, create a folder and save the image, it works normally, but when rotating the screen and click on share, I see that this bitmap null.
Does anyone have a solution? follow my code:

```
 public void onClick(View v) {
        if( mRecyclerViewOnClickListenerHack == null ) {
            OutputStream fOut = null;
            ImageView imgflag = (SimpleDraweeView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.iv_image);
            imgflag.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
            imgflag.buildDrawingCache();
            Bitmap bm=imgflag.getDrawingCache();

            File root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                    + File.separator + "ImageTop" + File.separator);
            root.mkdirs();
            File sdImageMainDirectory = new File(root, mList.get(getAdapterPosition()).getFoto());
            Uri imageUri = Uri.fromFile(sdImageMainDirectory);

            try {
            fOut = new FileOutputStream(sdImageMainDirectory);
                if (bm == null){
                Log.d(TAG, "Bitmap is null.");
                }else{
                bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 80, fOut);
                Log.d(TAG, "Bitmap is ok.");
                }

            Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
            sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageUri);
            sendIntent.setType("image/jpg");
                mContext.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, "Share"));

                fOut.flush();
                fOut.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Error.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }else{
            mRecyclerViewOnClickListenerHack.onClickListener(v, getAdapterPosition());
        }
    }
```

Already added configChange in manifest, but no solution.
I am a beginner in android and java.
Thanks to everyone who can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

onCreate method executes again when orientation changes. So probably when the orientation changes it cant get the image uri. So try to save and retrieve it from bundle.

Declare Uri p in class.

Add this in onCreate

```
p  =  yourImageUri;   // you image uri

if(savedInstanceState!=null) {
p= Uri.parse(savedInstanceState.getString("imageUri"));
}
```

And in class add this method.

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) 
{
outState.putExtra("imageUri", p.toString()); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but still did not work, I found another solution, I am using AsyncTask and copy the direct image.

Comment: I have another question, if you can help me, I will be grateful [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37836478/android-favorites-sharedpreferences-does-not-save-the-state